# Can handler pages (.ashx) get configuration settings?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, handler

Can a handler page (.ashx) get key values that are set in the app settings in the web.config? for asp.net

ANSWER: YES, see comments for details

Comment: Just like any other page/code. `var myString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"]`.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to confirm this

Comment: You could have tested that faster than typing the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get the settings using the `ConfigurationManager` class.

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]
```

More Information

- [MSDN - ConfigurationManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)